# Converting base5 to Octal without using Decimal

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I encountered a question that asks you to convert a Base-5 number: (434.21) into a Base-8 number. The only problem is that the question requires direct conversion without using Base-10, Decimal, conversion first.

Would like to know if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You know how to convert between base $n$ and base ten, by doing arithmetic in base ten.

You also know (hopefully, if you're given this question) how to do arithmetic in base 8 or 5.

If you do your arithmetic in base 8, you can use the "convert *into* my working base" algorithm.

Or you can do your arithmetic in base 5 and use the "convert *from* my working base" algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Write $434.21_5=\frac{43421_5}{100_5}$. Convert the numerator and denominator to base $8$:

$$43421_5 = 1_8 + 2\cdot 5_8+ 4\cdot 31_8 + 3\cdot 175_8 + 4\cdot1161_8$$
$$100_5=31_8$$

That's not going to be fun, but it is just calculation.

Then do the long division to compute the quotient in base $8$.

The base $8$ result will not be terminating, but will have a repeating digit sequence.

(It might be easier to convert $434_5$ to base $8$ (you should get $167_8$) then write $$0.21_5=\frac{21_5}{100_5}=\frac{15_8}{31_8}$$ and do the long division in base $8$ to compute that value.)

Comment: Where did you get the 31,175,1161 from?

Comment: $31_8=5^2$, $175_8=5^3, 1161_8=5^4$. @Adam

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's nothing special about base 10.
What you have to do is long division in base $5$, compute

$$434.21_5 \div 224_5 = A_2 + \frac{R_1}{224_5} \\
R_1 \div 13_5 = A_1 + \frac{R_2}{13_5} \\
\vdots$$
($225_5 = 13_5 \cdot 13_5 = 8^2$)
Where $A_i$ are within $0_5 = 0_8$ and $12_5 = 7_8$ so you can use digit substitution on them. What you essentially computed is
$$434.21_5 = A_2 \cdot 8^2 + A_1 \cdot 8^1 + \ldots$$
with $A_i$ represented in base $5$.

Answer (score 0):

> *Would like to know if it's even possible.*

It is, but this would obviously require operating directly in base-$5$. For this to be possible, we need to create a table for both addition and multiplication of base-$5$ digits, then use them to repeatedly divide the integer part of the number in question by “eight” $=5+3=13_5$, as well as repeatedly multiply its fractional part by the same quantity. Doing all these things does not require any use or previous knowledge of base-$10$.